# Prove either $P(A|B) \leq P(A) \leq P(A|B^{c})$ or $P(A|B) \geq P(A) \geq P(A|B^{c})$

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability, proof

Consider two events, A and B, on the same sample space. Prove that either $P(A|B) \leq P(A) \leq P(A|B^{c})$ or $P(A|B) \geq P(A) \geq P(A|B^{c})$.

Looking at the question, I believe I need to use the definition of conditional probability. But even then, I'm not exactly sure where to go with it. How should I start this?

Comment: Is this homework? If so add te self study tag.

Comment: What do E and F have to do with A and B?

Comment: @MichaelChernick Sorry, didn't mean to put E and F––I meant A and B.

Comment: I find it easier to reason about this circumstance by negating the assertion: is it really possible that the two conditional probabilities, $P(A\mid B)$ and $P(A\mid B^c)$, could both be strictly greater or strictly less than the probability of $A$ itself?

Answer (score 1):

So we have $ P(A)=P(A|B) P(B) +P(A|B^c)P(B^c)$

and $P(B)=P(B|A)P(A)+P(B|A^c) P(A^c)$ Note that whatever the sets A and B are either

**(a)**  $ 1>= P(A)>= P(B)>=0$

or

**(b)** $ 1>=P(B)>=P(A)>=0$

Assuming **(a)** gives one of the inequalities and **(b)** gives the other.

Comment: See if you can solve with the hints I have given you.

Comment: Michael, the hints are more confusing than helping:$$P(A)=P(A|B) P(B) +P(A|B^c)P(B^c)$$is all that is needed to prove the result, while **(a)** and **(b)** do not separate between the two orderings.